# Special permissions for anonymous user in Hasura engine

Tags: hasura

Hello Hasura community!

I'm building a very simple app where Anonymous users will be able to place orders.

I basically have two tables with these fields:

- `order`

  - id
  - email
  - address_id
  - status
- `order_address`

  - id
  - street
  - number

I have two issues to resolve around Permissions:

### Issue 1

In order to allow `Anonymous` users to place the orders, I have to give them insert permission in both: `order` and `order_address` tables and use the `insert_order` mutation.

The problem I have is that by doing this, the mutation `insert_order_address` is also made available to the `anonymous` users, so they can directly insert addresses not belonging to their orders.

**Is there any way I can only allow inserting addresses through the insert_order mutation?**

(`Allow-List` won’t be an option for me because manager users still need to insert addresses directly)

### Issue 2

When an Anonymous user creates an order, I want to return to her the autogenerated order `id` (a UUID), so the user can later track its order.

The only way I found to return the `id` to the user, is by granting select permission “Without any checks” to `anonymous` users in the `id` column, but if I do so, anyone will be able to retrieve all the order ids.

**Is there any way to achieve this without exposing all the ids?**

Thanks in advance!!

### UPDATE (adding structure and mutations)

#### `order` table

##### Columns

- `id` - uuid, primary key, unique, default: gen_random_uuid()
- `email` - text
- `address_id` - uuid, nullable
- `status` - text, nullable

##### Foreign Keys

address_id → order_address . id - order_address_id_fkey

##### Object relationships

address
order . address_id  → order_address . id

##### Mutation

```
mutation MyMutation {
  insert_order(objects: {address: {data: {number: "", street: ""}}}) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

### `order_address` table

#### Columns

- `id` - uuid, primary key, unique, default: gen_random_uuid()
- `street` - text
- `number` - numeric

#### Mutation

```
mutation MyMutation {
  insert_order_address(objects: {number: "", street: ""}) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

Comment: A. "Allow-List won’t be an option for me because admin users still need to insert addresses directly" - Allow List is only for non-admin users. So `admin` users will be able to do everything with registered objects. B. Hasura can insert related objects in one mutation: orders and related addresses in your case. And with combination with Allow-List you can allow only this kind of mutation. C. " return to her the autogenerated order id" - can you show structures and mutations? There must not be problems with that

Comment: Hi @AlexYu, thanks for replying.

A. When I said "admin" I meant an app Administrator, which will have a "manager" role, not the default Hasura admin role.

B. From (A) I don't think I'll be able to use Allow-List, so anonymous users will still be able to insert addresses directly through insert_order_address mutation.

C. I added this to the main question because is too long to be added in the comment.

Thanks!

Comment: I formatted  question a bit - take a look if everything OK

Comment: Looks great, thanks @AlexYu!